# Много серверов у одного сайта

Tags: сервер

Как работает система серверов у крупных компаний как Вконтакте, FaceBook и т.п.
На одном сервере не уместить столько информации сколько у этих социальных сетей 
Как реализуется это?

Comment: это называется sharding. гуглите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front-end + back-end + cache + database - более менее общая схема.
Все это масштабируется и оптимизируется в зависимости от конкретных нужд.

1. Front-end принимает запросы и
       отвечает на них, на нем вся статика. 
       Загрузка и отдача данных. Чаще всего это nginx.
2. Back-end обрабатывает запросы,
       исполняет скрипты, работает с БД и
       кэшем. Чаще всего это Apache.
3. Кэши - это сервера посредники с
       небольшими объемами хранилищ, где
       хранится "горячая" информация,
       которую пользователи запрашивают
       чаще всего.
4. База данных - основные хранилища
       информации.

Answer (score 0):

```
 не уместить столько информации
```

Если речь идёт про базы данных, то так (на примере социалки):

У профиля пользователя есть уникальный id. Первый пользователь социалки имеет id 1, 195 863ий - 195 863. Данные для пользователей 1-100 хранятся на 1 сервере, 101-200 на втором и т.д.

Comment: Нет я про сервера  ну например там же 100000 видюшек, и аудио записей, и фоток

Comment: Так 1ое - 100ое видео храниться на первом сервере, 101 - 200 на втором и т.д.

Comment: Ну,  а сам сайт. Сайт же нельзя разбить на несколько частей

Comment: Читайте про кластеры серверов. Это невозможно объяснить здесь и уложиться в пару строк.